# Jquery not working. I can´t figure it out

Tags: jquery, html

Coded this function I´m not being able to find why is not working.

I know the JS file is loaded because other functions inside it are working, but those with this format not:

```
$(function () {
....
});
```

The idea is to show a modal windows when you click in a specific div (class addWidget), after that Jquery function will count some divs and show them in the modal window (before) for check them if you want.

The code is the next one:

-- JQUERY --

```
$(function () {
    $('.addWidget').on('click', function () {
        $('.modal-body').empty();
        $('.modal-title').text('Añadir Widget');
        $('.box:hidden').each(function () {
            $('.modal-body').append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"> ' + $(this).attr('name') + '</input><br />');
        });
        if ($('.modal-body').children('input').length > 0) {
            $('#modal').modal('show');
        } else {
            $('.modal-title').empty();
            $('.modal-body').text('Todos los widgets estan desplegados');
            $('#modal').modal('show');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

When I clicked in the div, nothing happens... :(

EDITED:

Trying this approach, at least, is entering in my Jquery´s function:

```
function addWigdet() {
    $('.modal-body').empty();
    $('.modal-title').text('Añadir Widget');
    $('.box:hidden').each(function () {
        $('.modal-body').append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"> ' + $(this).attr('name') + '</input><br />');
    });
    if ($('.modal-body').children('input').length > 0) {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    } else {
        $('.modal-title').empty();
        $('.modal-body').text('Todos los widgets estan desplegados');
        $('#modal').modal('show');
        return false;
    };
} (jQuery);

onclick="javascript:addWigdet()"
```

But:

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

Crash... Something about this element doesn´t support **modal('show')**...

Comment: Your browser has a console that displays JavaScript errors. Find it. It's often behind F12.

Comment: Please, add full code. Also open the console browser and see if you add jquery correctly. If show an error like "$ is not defined" is because you not add jquery correctly

Comment: Is your `.addWidget` element present on the page when the code runs?

Comment: is this js code in a js file or inside your html?

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález. Yep, I tried. Even using the Visual Studio debugger for Jquery. Just is not entering in the function. But it´s entering in athother javascript´s functions.

Comment: @Netzach. I tried. Full code is so extensive. Do you need it really? That error doesn´t appear. And another jquery´s functions inside in JS file are working...

Comment: @NevilleNazerane. Yep, it´s.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane. Code it´s in a JS File.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your "I tried" reply to my "Find the console" tip. You were not able to find the browser console? Unless you're using a really old browser from the 1990s there should be a console. If you are not sure of what browser you are using you can normally read the name in the title bar of the window.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález. Hahaha, Sorry, I mean I did it but it is not working. Errors is not appearing. Even more, I did a debug by VS using IE and I check how is not entering in the function. I´m tried another approach which look like is entering in the function at least. You know the strange of this, this exactly project worked one month ago... :S

Comment: Alright... Not seeing errors in the console doesn't mean the console is broken anyway. If you mean that `$()` doesn't execute the anonymous function you pass as parameter you must be overwriting `$` with some other library. You'd better use the `jQuery()` syntax.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález. I edited my question... Could it give you a clue?

Comment: Are you sure your diagnostic of `$()` not executing is right? I feel it's executing but selectors do not match any element.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's not a typo? You use both `addWigdet` and `addWidget` in your code

Comment: @DarrenSweeney. Sorry, what do you mean with a typo?

Comment: I mean you're spelling the same word differently `addWidget != addWigdet` - I'm not saying this is the problem but just to check you haven't mixed them up somewhere in the code

Comment: @DarrenSweeney. Check it. It´s not the problem :(

Comment: Then I suggest creating a fiddle - it will help us see the code in action

Comment: @DarrenSweeney. Did it. Is the first time I´m using it (so if something is wrong let me know it please) and I believe you can go on from my question but here is anyway. :) .https://jsfiddle.net/EliasMP/5xyrr3mq/3/

Comment: It works fine - click the + and look at console http://www.bootply.com/ZetrKNhaRx

Comment: @DarrenSweeney. I tried it. Following your link I click in the + and nothing happens... wtf! Sorry, I forgot to implement the modal window. I updated the fiddle. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Finally Found it. Just sharing for avoiding this problem if you all have the same issue.

I solved taking another way, probably, not the proper one but fix it.

The problem is related with something about using the master page and loading the specific jquery function inside, so, for fix this specific problem with this specific function (really odd, other functions working out), I decided to load the function in each page which need it...

Hoping it works for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
(function ($) {
    ....
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @EliasMP What does `console.log(jQuery, typeof jQuery)` show?

Comment: Between other errors: Cadena vacía pasada a getElementById().jquery-1.10.2.js:188:12
function m() functionHomeScript.js:34:5
function m() functionHomeScript.js:45:9
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: @EliasMP You said the console didn't display any error?

Comment: Errors related with another part of the code.... @ÁlvaroGonzález. I posted you the specific ones...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález. Dont you think is strange sortable is not recognized now?

Comment: @EliasMP Sorry, this problem has gone beyond my ability to debug stuff. Everething's too confusing for me.

Comment: It´s fine. You tried it. :). Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález